# Mostrar valor en % grafico de barras chartJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

estoy trabajando en un grafico de barras con chartJs y le agregué la opción de "anchor" para mostrar los valores dentro de la grafica de barras, sin embargo me gustaría que mostrara el signo '%' al lado del valor, como sería eso posible?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
const barsChartOptions = computed<ChartOptions<'bar'>>(() => ({
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
              x: {
                ticks: { 
                  callback: function(value) {
                    return `${value}%`;
                }
              },
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Cumplimiento',

                  font: {
                    family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
                    size: 10,
                    lineHeight: 1.2,
                  },
                  padding: { top: 15, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 11 },
                },
                grid: {
                  display: true,
                  drawBorder: false,
                  font: {
                    size: 9,
                    family: 'Montserrat-Regular',
                  },
                },
                beginAtZero: true,
              },
              y: {
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Proveedor',
                  font: {
                    family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
                    size: 10,
                    lineHeight: 1.2,
                  },
                  padding: { top: 15, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 11 },
                },
                grid: {
                  display: false,
                  drawBorder: false,
                },
              },
            },
            plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                anchor: 'center',
                color: 'white',
              },
              
              legend: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
          }));

          const dataSet = cumplimientoUseCase.mapDataset(
            this.cumplimientoGetter as TCumplimientoProveedorDTO[],
          );
          const dataValues = computed<ChartData<'bar'>>(() => ({
            labels: dataSet.labels,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: dataSet.datasets,
                backgroundColor: [
                  '#1d864a',
                  '#fcc832',
                  '#347fab',
                  '#ab6034',
                  '#7834ab',
                  '#4b75e3',
                  '#bef539',
                  '#769b81',
                ],
                barThickness: 20,
                barPercentage: 1,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                font: {
                  size: 9,
                },
              },
            ],
          }));
          const { barChartProps } = useBarChart({
            chartData: dataValues,
            options: barsChartOptions,
          });
          this.cumplimientoOptions = barChartProps;
        });
```

Comment: Hola, muestra lo que has hecho hasta ahora para obtener ese resultado, si lo compartes quizás podremos solucionar tu problema.

Agrega el código en donde obtienes ese resultado.

Comment: Hola! acabo de agregar mi código, ojalá puedas ayudarme :(

Comment: dentro de la propieedad 'datalabels', 'anchor' es donde realiza la acción de agregar el número a la barra

Comment: Revisando tu código no se aprecia la parte que dices, pero si quieres agregar solo el signo, concatena tu _variable_ que pinta el valor de dicha barra con el _string_, ejemplo: **data+'%';**